# Bind KeyBinding Command to WPF DatePicker (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, prism

I've been searching high and low for a way to bind the Return key to a DatePicker control in a MVVM way, but to no avail.

My current XAML Markup:

```xml
<DatePicker x:Name="DateFilter" SelectedDate="{Binding SearchDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <DatePicker.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}"></KeyBinding>
    </DatePicker.InputBindings>
</DatePicker>
```

The closest thing I found is rewriting the entire control template, but this both requires a lot of markup and screws up the original control appearance.

Right now, I've hacked a solution together by forcefully adding the DatePicker InputBindings to the underlying DatePickerTextBox from the form codebehind, but it's awful as it requires writing code behind and uses reflection:

Form CodeBehind (bound to the Loaded event of the view):

```cs
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fiTextBox = typeof(DatePicker)
        .GetField("_textBox", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (fiTextBox?.GetValue(DateFilter) is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DatePickerTextBox textBox)
    {
        textBox.InputBindings.AddRange(DateFilter.InputBindings);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

(Note: I cannot bind the execution of the command to the change of the bound SearchDate property as the operation is quite expensive and I don't want it to fire every time the user picks a new date. However, I need the property to immediately refresh as the CanExecute of the command is also tied to said Date not being null.)

Comment: what's wrong with searching at all date changes (in the background, with a wait indicator, cancelling an old search if a new starts...) ? from a ux perspective, it sounds weird to have to select a date (by mouse or touch, perhaps) and then having to press the enter key to tell the system that the date is now selected for real.

Comment: @Haukinger it might sound ridiculous, but our users are particularly clumsy. What this tries to accomplish is to avoid people from mistakenly change the date and have the search results change while the user is still working on the previous set. Forcing them to press an additional key or button allows us to be sure they actually want to perform a search (BTW, there is also a "Search" button in the UI).

Comment: Does Enter close the picker? Couldn't you just trigger off Closed instead?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I need it to also work when directly entering the date on the textbox

Answer (score 2):

You could use a reusable attached behaviour:

```
public static class ReturnKeyBehavior
{
    public static ICommand GetCommand(UIElement UIElement) =>
        (ICommand)UIElement.GetValue(CommandProperty);

    public static void SetCommand(UIElement UIElement, ICommand value) =>
        UIElement.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Command",
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ReturnKeyBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnCommandChanged));

    private static void OnCommandChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uie = (UIElement)d;

        ICommand oldCommand = e.OldValue as ICommand;
        if (oldCommand != null)
            uie.RemoveHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)OnMouseLeftButtonDown);

        ICommand newCommand = e.NewValue as ICommand;
        if (newCommand != null)
            uie.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)OnMouseLeftButtonDown, true);
    }

    private static void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            UIElement uie = (UIElement)sender;
            ICommand command = GetCommand(uie);
            if (command != null)
                command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

...that can be attached to any UIElement in XAML:

```
<DatePicker local:ReturnKeyBehavior.Command="{Binding ListViewItemMouseLeftButtonDownCommand}" />
```

Then you don't have to deal with any keys in the view model.

Comment: Nice! I edited the code a bit to also allow a CommandParameter object and consider the CanExecute of the command and it works like a charm. (I'll leave the question open for a bit more before marking an answer)

Comment: With all due respect to mm8, I would argue that this is still code-behind. Just because it's abstracted into a behavior doesn't really change the fact that it's still basically the same code. It's still in the view, it still can't be unit tested without the view layer being present and in this particular example it's hard-coded to a specific key. Whenever you find yourself using things like behaviors and converters to implement application-specific GUI logic it's often a sign that the view model layer isn't doing its job properly.

Comment: @MarkFeldman: MVVM is *not* about eliminating code from the views. It's about separation of concerns. If you don't intend to reuse this functionality across several `UIElements`, you might as well implement it in the code-behind of the view. The view model knows about the command and the logic it encapsulates. It doesn't care about how the command is invoked. That's the responsibility of the view in this case. Your example uses an `EventTrigger` to invoke the command and mine uses a behavior. Both belongs to the view.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use an interaction trigger, or whatever else your framework uses to convert events to commands, and then trap PreviewKeyDown:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="DateFilter" SelectedDate="{Binding SearchDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd ="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding KeyDownCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DatePicker>
```

And then in your view model:

```
private ICommand _KeyDownCommand;
public ICommand KeyDownCommand => this._KeyDownCommand ?? (this._KeyDownCommand = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(OnKeyDown));

private void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I also considered that and it would work for sure. Just a question though, isn't checking for what key has been pressed a violation of MVVM by making the vm aware it's receiving a keyboard event?

Comment: Not at all. The golden rule is that if it's GUI behavior you should be unit testing then it belongs in the view model. Invoking a command in response to a specific key press is most definitely behavior you should be unit testing.